# make: Reverse a path

Tags: path, makefile

suppose I have a makefile in the folder `/d/e/f`. In that makefile I have got a relative path in a variable, lets say it is MYPATH:=`../../a`.

Now, I want to somehow retrieve the reverse path, i.e., if perform a `cd $(MYPATH)` what would be the path to get back to the makefile. E.g., in this case, the answer should be `../e/f`.

Is this somehow possible?

Rationale: I want to be able to hand in a path into my makefile. The makefile at that path should be included, i.e. `include $(MYPATH)`, but before that, the variable $(HOME_PATH) should be set to the relative path from $(MYPATH) back to the makefile, so the included makefile can supply rules based on the path of the calling makefile.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use relative paths?  If you use absolute paths (for example, run `$(abspath $(MYPATH))` then it's trivial.  Trying to invert the path using make functions will not be fun.  At all.

Comment: I'm a little confused why you want the makefile to flow in this direction. Generally I would expect a makefile in a higher directory to call makefiles in deeper directories. I.E. makefile in dir a calls makefile in dir f is something more in-line with what I've seen done.